# how to store for loop string data in Array out side of the for loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb, for-loop

```
Customer dtls = new Customer();
String missing = dtls.getList(stingName, intAge, intMob, stingDOB);
JSONArray mJsonArray_miss_dtls = new JSONArray(missing);
String miss = "";
for (int k = 0; k < mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject missingObject = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.getJSONObject(k);
    String s1 = missingObject.getString("DOB");
    String[] b = s1.split("T");
    String[] b1 = b[0].split("-");
    miss = b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];
    cnt++;
}
```

Here i want to store "miss ( string)" data into an Array outside of the for loop where i can store all data of this for loop in a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the miss variable inside the loop and the result Array outside the loop, then when you are in the loop, add the miss variable into the res array.

```
Customer dtls = new Customer();
String missing = dtls.getList(stingName, intAge, intMob, stingDOB);
JSONArray mJsonArray_miss_dtls = new JSONArray(missing);
Integer length = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length();
String[] res= new String[lenght];
for (int k = 0; k < lenght; k++) {
    String miss = "";
    JSONObject missingObject = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.getJSONObject(k);
    String s1 = missingObject.getString("DOB");
    String[] b = s1.split("T");
    String[] b1 = b[0].split("-");
    miss = b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];
    res[k]=miss;
    cnt++;
}
```

A more compacted solution:

```
Customer dtls = new Customer();
String missing = dtls.getList(stingName, intAge, intMob, stingDOB);
JSONArray mJsonArray_miss_dtls = new JSONArray(missing);
Integer length = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length();
String[] res= new String[lenght];
for (int k = 0; k < lenght; k++) {
    JSONObject missingObject = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.getJSONObject(k);
    String s1 = missingObject.getString("DOB");
    String[] b = s1.split("T");
    String[] b1 = b[0].split("-");
    res[k]=b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to declare the `miss` variable inside the loop, but it is recommended. Also no need to initialize it with the empty string... actually there is no real need for that variable at all (but eventually debugging)

Comment: Yeah but since he was asking about the miss variable, I declared it for clarification tho it would be possible to use `res[k]=b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];`

Comment: String[mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length()] res;      showing error

Comment: when i use res[i]=slipDate.replace("[","").replace("]",""); it shows (java.lang.NullPointerException)java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @KrishanuDebnath I think I corrected it by changing the way I declare the array.

Comment: thanks a lot, @DanielDiment... Now its work exactly okay. But when I try to print this res[k] outside of the loop. then I am unable to print it.

Comment: ex = >No current context (stack frame)<

Comment: when i print only "res" instead of "res[k] it shows output as "[Ljava.lang.String;@3ea9d513" or when i print res[k] i got  error message "No current context (stack frame)"

Comment: @KrishanuDebnath I think the k variable is not declared outside the for loop, if you want to print all the contents of the array you should make a new for loop that for every String of the array it prints it.

Comment: for (int p = 0; p < lenght; p++) {System.out.println(res[p])} It should work with that code.

Comment: My target is :-
Customer dtls = new Customer();
String missing = dtls.getList(stingName, intAge, intMob, stingDOB);
JSONArray mJsonArray_miss_dtls = new JSONArray(missing);
Integer length = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length();
String[] res= new String[lenght];
for (int k = 0; k < lenght; k++) {
    JSONObject missingObject = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.getJSONObject(k);
    String s1 = missingObject.getString("DOB");
    String[] b = s1.split("T");
    String[] b1 = b[0].split("-");
    res[k]=b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];
    cnt++;
}
System.out.println(res[k]);
is it possile???

Comment: For that case i found java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It should be:  Customer dtls = new Customer();
 String missing = dtls.getList(stingName, intAge, intMob, stingDOB);
 JSONArray mJsonArray_miss_dtls = new JSONArray(missing);
 Integer length = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.length();
 String[] res= new String[lenght];
 for (int k = 0; k < lenght; k++) { 
 JSONObject missingObject = mJsonArray_miss_dtls.getJSONObject(k); 
 String s1 = missingObject.getString("DOB"); 
 String[] b = s1.split("T"); String[] b1 = b[0].split("-");
 res[k]=b1[0] + "/" + b1[1];
 cnt++; 
} 
for (int p = 0; p < lenght; p++) {
 System.out.println(res[p])
}